Control treatments are significantly different
I want to compare different treatments in Naive and Exposed tadpoles (N/C, N/S, E/C, E/S) but I can't say something about the difference between N/S and E/S because the control treatments (N/C and E/C) are significantly different.
I tried to calculate the difference of the treatments with the respective controlvalues but then I had some negative values so a poisson distribution was not applicable anymore. After that, I transformed the adjusted values so I only had positive values but then I had p-values of 1. How can I compare the other treatments while the control treatments are different from each other?

Please browse the site's help center, but particularly the section about what the expectations are to have your question be on-topic for stackoverflow. Unless you edit your question to include some programming component and corresponding source code with which others can reproduce your issue, you should probably expect your question to get closed as off-topic.
